# How to edit jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have downloaded the latest jQuery version, placed it into the website's folder and added the following code into my index.html

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

My question is, where should I enter the actual jQuery code I want to use? Thanks.

Comment: at the bottom of the page just before the `</body>` tag

Comment: either you can write on your page or in external file and refer to that file in your page

Comment: you can use it anywhere you want , it depends on your requirement

Comment: Add the code anywhere under your jquery script tag

Comment: I recommend to read some basic tutorials. E.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript and http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Main_Page (especially http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Your_first_look_at_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either inline in a  block, or in another JS file you are linking within your header. Ideally below the line you posted.

Comment: Thank you, how should I link to another JS file? What code should I use? I'm guessing not the same as the above '<script src"file"</script>'

Comment: Actually, <script src='myfilename.js'></script> would work nicely.

Comment: _"Ideally below the line you posted."_ - What do you mean "ideally"? It _has_ to be below that line or it won't work.

Comment: @nnnnnn that's the joke. Lighten up a little. It's almost weekend :)

Comment: Thank you Martin, it works great! Sorry for the noob question :)

Comment: Oh, a joke, right. I just didn't want the OP to get confused. (And I _wish_ it was almost the weekend, but still two more work days to go. Ugh.)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is nothing but a JavaScript framework (albeit a great framework). If you're starting out on your front-end web development journey, I would suggest looking at JavaScript in conjunction with jQuery as it is the building block of the framework and will help you to understand how it works better.
**You can use inline jQuery or a different javascript(.js) file(better to ues).**

Answer (score 0):

Either inline on the index.html like so:

```
<script>

/* jquery code goes here */

</script>
```

Or you can link to another js file like so:

```
<script src="your_folder/jquery_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: In the first example, the code inside the script will be ignored (since you are loading a JS file specified by the `src` attribute).

Comment: thanks Felix I didnt notice that :D